# Why use this.get('serviceName') instead of this.serviceName?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, ember-cli

In Ember.JS, Is there a good reason to be doing this:

```
import Service, { inject } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
ajax: inject(),
getAll() {
    return this.get('ajax').request(`api/users/`, {
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
});
```

As opposed to this?

```
import Service, { inject } from '@ember/service';

export default Service.extend({
ajax: inject(),
getAll() {
    return this.ajax.request(`api/users/`, {
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
});
```

The second method looks cleaner IMO, but I'm wondering if there's a good functional reason to be using .get() over just referencing the service directly.

Answer (score 9):

the future is `this.whateverProperty`.

`this.get` was implemented in a time where JS lacked a lot of features, and a lot of documentation has yet to be updated.

The official ember guides are already updated:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/#toc_accessing-services

as of Ember 3.1, you can use native getters everywhere.

Comment: I'd add that addons (which generally support the last 2 LTS releases are not quite ready to drop `get`. They will be very soon (when 3.8 becomes the next LTS release).

Comment: ES5 getters for computed properties are supported since 3.1: https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2018/04/13/ember-3-1-released.html#toc_es5-getters-for-computed-properties-2-of-4 Major releases (`.0`) of Ember.js don't contain any new features but only remove deprecated API. Many addons are supporting more than 2 LTS releases.